# Python: For each directory in the working directory go into that directory and get the name of the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, navigation, directory

I need to make a script that will iterate through all the directories inside a directory. It should go into each directory, get its name and save it to a variable and comes back out, and then loops.

```
    for dir in os.walk(exDir):
        path = dir
        os.chdir(path)
        source = #dir trimmed to anything after the last /
        os.chdir("..")
    loops
```

It needs to go into the directory to do other things not mentioned above. I've only just started Python and have been stuck on this problem for the last day or so.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `os.walk()`?   It returns a tuple.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: @cdarke I hadn't looked closely enough clearly. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each iteration of your for loop, `dir` is a tuple of format `(filepath, subdirectories, files)`. As such `dir[0]` will give you the filepath.

It sounds like you just want to `os.chdir` for each folder recursively in `exDir` in which case the following will work:

```
for dir in os.walk(exDir):
    os.chdir(dir[0])
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Seems to be what I needed.